# How to extract nested json value in a html table row using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to get the object number from an array in this HTML table. And I am also trying to get the key and value of the data object in this JSON array. I have tried with this code and do not know how to proceed in the red marked area of the code. Can anyone help me to find what is missing?

```js
var myArray = []

$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'url',
  success: function(response) {
    myArray = response
    buildTable(myArray)
    console.log(myArray)
  }
})

function buildTable(data) {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = `<tr>
      <td>${data[i].}</td> // Row number
      <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(0, 10)}</td>
      <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(11, 19)}</td>
      <td>${data[i].data.}</td> // Measurement type, the key of data object
      <td>${data[i].data.}</td> // Measurement type, the value of the data object
    </tr>`
    table.innerHTML += row
  }
}
```

```css
th {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr class="bg-info">
    <th>Row Number</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Measurement Type</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody id="myTable">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

[The browser image is here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah4JipYWb-3Bgdli4bxFTVGAJEU8ng?e=Jq24rg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve your problem:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    th{ 
        color:#fff;
            }
</style>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr  class="bg-info">
        <th>Row Number</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Measurement Type</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">
        
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var myArray = []

   $.ajax({
     method:'GET',
     url:'http://webapi19sa-1.course.tamk.cloud/v1/weather',
     success:function(response){
        myArray = response
        buildTable(myArray)
        console.log(myArray)
     }
   })

    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].id}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(0, 10)}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(11, 19)}</td>
                     <td>${Object.keys(data[i].data)[0]}</td> 
                     <td>${data[i].data[Object.keys(data[i].data)[0]]}</td> </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row


        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: looks like a copy of an earlier answer with missing sanitation, so if the key in data would be not available whole code would error

Comment: Thanks to all. It was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract key before building table:

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url:'http://webapi19sa-1.course.tamk.cloud/v1/weather',
    success:function(response){
      buildTable(response)
      console.log(response)
    }
  })

  function buildTable(data){
    const table = document.getElementById('myTable')

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const measurements = Object.keys(data[i].data);
      const value = measurements.length ? data[i].data[measurements[0]] : '';
      const name = measurements.length ? measurements[0] : '';

      const row = `
        <tr>
          <td>${i}</td>
          <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(0, 10)}</td>
          <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(11, 19)}</td>
          <td>${name}</td> 
          <td>${value}</td>
        </tr>`
      table.innerHTML += row
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OP did not make use of the power of jQuery in any way. So, I took the liberty of removing jQuery here altogether. As `.innerHTML+=` is an "expensive" operation (it requires the DOM to be rebuilt every time) I replaced it by a faster `innerHTML=` assignment "outside the loop":

```js
fetch('http://webapi19sa-1.course.tamk.cloud/v1/weather')
.then(r=>r.json())
.then(data=>document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML=data.map(d=>`<tr>
  <td>${d.id}</td>
  <td>${d.date_time.substring(0,10)}</td>
  <td>${d.date_time.substring(11, 19)}</td>
  <td>${Object.entries(d.data||{"":""})[0].join('</td><td>')}</td></tr>`
 ).join('')
);
```

```css
th{color:#fff;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr  class="bg-info">
        <th>Row Number</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Measurement Type</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With

```
Object.entries(d.data||{"":""})[0].join('</td><td>')
```

I get the first ( `[0]`) key and value of an object (`.d.data`). This expression will not break id `d.data` should be empty or even be non-existent.